# Make AppBar flow out of container - Material UI - React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox, material-ui

I am wrapping up my app inside a MUI Container with maxWidth set to false. I have an AppBar inside the container and I want the AppBar to take the whole screen width, but the container enforces a paddingX property which prevents the AppBar from extending towards the end of the viewport. Could you please help me out on this?

This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  AppBar,
  Box,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Button,
} from '@mui/material';
import './style.scss';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container maxWidth={false} component="main">
        <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <AppBar position="static" className="extend-width">
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                News
              </Typography>
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

main.MuiContainer-root {
  .extend-width {
    position: relative;
    width: 95vw;
    left: calc(-47.5vw + 50%);
  }
}
```

Stackblitz link: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-r9mpqs?file=App.tsx,style.scss)

The AppBar inside Container should look like the AppBar outside the container.

Expected output is that anything with the class **extend-width** should extend to the ends of the viewport.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you set padding of container to 0?

Comment: I want the padding to exist for all the contents inside it. I do want only the AppBar or elements with the class to extend

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution is to remove padding from container and instead use another container inside to wrap items with padding and exclude appbar.
2. More dirty options is to use negative margin:

```
.app-bar {
  margin: 0 -24px; // Replace by theme.spacing or actual padding values
  width: calc(100% + 48px); //100% + marginX
}
```